# For all $n\in\Bbb N$ show $9\mid(16^n+12n-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

This an exercise that I found in a maths book from the first lesson in the second year of high school called *Logic*. Here we have to demonstrate the proposition by reasoning with recurrences.

> Show that for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $9\mid(16^n+12n-1)$.

*I tried to solve this by recurrences but I keep getting false and illogical answers!*

Answer (score 1):

As regards 1), I guess that you would like to show that $9$ divides $16^n+12n-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Hint. Try induction and note that
$$16^{n+1}+12(n+1)-1=(18-2)16^{n}+(36-24)n+11\\
=18\cdot 16^n+36n+9-2(16^n+12n-1).$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard method for (1). After checking the $n=0$ case, suppose the statement holds for $n$, that is
$$
16^n+12n-1=9t
$$
for some integer $t$. This can also be written as $16^n=9t-12n+1$. Then
\begin{align}
16^{n+1}+12(n+1)-1
&=16(9t-12n+1)+12n+11 \\
&=9\cdot 16t-15\cdot 12n+27 \\
&=9(16t-20n+3)
\end{align}

I'll show another strategy for (2). You can subtract the expressions for the case $n$ from the one for the case $n+1$:
\begin{align}
(1+5^{n+2}+2\cdot3^{n+1})-(1+5^{n+1}+2\cdot3^{n})
&=5^{n+2}-5^{n+1}+2\cdot 3^{n+1}-2\cdot 3^{n}\\
&=4\cdot5^{n+1}-4\cdot3^n \\
&=4(5^{n+1}-3^n)
\end{align}
Since $5^{n+1}-3^n$ is even, you're done, because the afore mentioned difference is divisible by $8$. Since the case $n=0$ is true, this ends the proof.

Comment: I've deleted my comment, but the congrats stands!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

1. $\ds{ n = 9\left\lfloor{n \over 9}\right\rfloor + r_{n}\,,\
   16^{n} = 9\left\lfloor{16^{n} \over 9}\right\rfloor + s_{n}\,,\qquad\qquad 
   \left\vert\
   \begin{array}{rcl}
   && \ds{r_{n} \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}\quad \mid\quad r_{n} < 9}
   \\[5mm]
   \ds{s_{n}} & \ds{=} &
   \left\{\begin{array}{ccrcl}
   \ds{1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{n} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
   \\
   \ds{7} & \mbox{if} & \ds{n} & \ds{=} & \ds{1}
   \\
   \ds{4} & \mbox{if} & \ds{n} & \ds{=} & \ds{2}
   \\
   \ds{s_{n - 3}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{n} & \ds{\geq} & \ds{3}
   \end{array}\right.\end{array}\right.}$

   ---

   \begin{align}
   16^{n} + 12n - 1 & = \varepsilon + s_{n} + 3r_{n} - 1\quad\mbox{where}\quad 9 \mid \varepsilon
   \end{align}

   ---

   $\ds{s_{n} + 3r_{n} - 1}$ is periodic of period $\ds{9}$. Then,
   $\underline{\textit{it is sufficient}}$ to prove that $\ds{9 \mid \pars{s_{n} + 3n - 1}}$ for
   $\ds{n = 0, 1, 2,\ldots 8}$ which is quite trivial:
   $$
   \begin{array}{cc}\hline
   \ds{n\quad} & \ds{\quad s_{n} + 3n - 1}
   \\ \hline
   \ds{0} & \ds{0}
   \\
   \ds{1} & \ds{9}
   \\
   \ds{2} & \ds{9}
   \\
   \ds{3} & \ds{9}
   \\
   \ds{4} & \ds{18}
   \\
   \ds{5} & \ds{18}
   \\
   \ds{6} & \ds{18}
   \\
   \ds{7} & \ds{27}
   \\
   \ds{8} & \ds{27}
   \\ \hline
   \end{array}
   $$

> Question $\ds{\left.2\right)}$ follows a similar technique and question $\ds{\left.3\right)}$ is rather trivial.